# Application or web service to show the travel time between two locations

Tags: gps, mapping, web-services

I'm looking for an application or web service that can:

- show the travel time between two locations for every 7 day of the week and every hour: I want to drive from X to Y and I have the choice of the day and hour, so I'd like to pick to best day/hour.

And if possible:

- works on Windows 7 or Android
- free
- I don't want to have to scrape Google Maps or other map services
- also show the fastest path

Comment: What type of travel - commute, cross-state, international? Which location are you in?

Comment: Driving within the US

Comment: Do you know if your city collects traffic density data?  Without that (and even then it would need to be publicly available) I don't see this happening...of course without using a program you can hedge your bets...avoid standard peak traffic times, (6:30 to 9, 11 to 1 and 3:30 to 6) and test out routes...

Comment: My city collects traffic density data to some extent: http://www.mhd.state.ma.us/default.asp?pgid=content/traffic01&sid=about ; another way to get data would be to [crowdsource like Google Maps do](http://www.theconnectivist.com/2013/07/how-google-tracks-traffic/).

Comment: If anyone has any idea please add an answer.

Comment: I haven't found anything so far.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt, have you tried any of [off-the-shelf scraping tools](http://scraping.pro/software-for-web-scraping/)? If you need only to `show a travel time` you might be interested in [Handy Web Extractor](http://scraping.pro/handy-web-extractor/).